# What is this character: ⿺见↷见 / ⿺見↷見?

Tags: characters

Yesterday, March 3rd '21, in advance of IRG Meeting No. 56, IRG posted document: [IRGN2469](https://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eirg/irg/irg56/IRG56.htm), entitled [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension H](https://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Eirg/irg/irg56/IRGN2469_CJK-ExtH.pdf). One of the characters in the document grabbed my attention:

> [image]

Or

> ⿺见↷见

[BabelStone PUA](https://babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/PUA.html) also lists this character

> [image]

But BabelStone's link to the original Tweet:

> [See @JUMANJIKYO (拾萬字鏡) on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JUMANJIKYO/status/1077599757021790208)

Seems to link to ⿴囗回 instead of ⿺见↷见 or ⿺見↷見

Any ideas what this character is about?

Comment: Is `↷` a valid ideographic description character?

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure - I just copied it from Andrew's work really

Comment: @dROOOze I can tell you it does *not* occur in the CJK IDS which is the first thing I checked when I saw this post!!

Comment: The correct IDS seems to be 〾⿺见见, but the leading 〾 doesn’t seem to really help that specifically.

Comment: I hope they introduce things like ↷ formally, as we currently don't have the ability to specify rotated or mirrored components. I'm surprised people would make up a character like ⿺见↷见 though, as it doesn't seem to be even writable using common strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidence provided by the [UK](https://hc.jsecs.org/irg/ws2017/app/index.php?find=UK-10909) shows:

> 《江西省信丰县地名志》(1987) page 378
> [image]

- ⿺见↷见 = hidden

Now you see it...now you don't, I guess?

Comment: What is the character in the last row? The image is not very clear.

Comment: @Sweeper ⿵门见 a simplified form of  (U+28D3C). On BabelStone PUA it is:  (U+E72D). In CJK Unified Ideographs Extension H it has been allotted the temporary code point: 32244.